# Can you compare a variable to NULL with the exact operator?

Tags: php

```
<?php
  // connect to db
  require_once 'mysql.php';
  $connection = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
  if ($connection->connect_error) die("Whoops.");
  // check token
  $token = $_REQUEST[token];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM newusers WHERE token='$token'";
  $result = $connection->query($query);

  if (!$result)
  {
    echo "Nothing to activate.";
    die("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=index.php'>");
  }
  else ($result->num_rows)
  {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    $result->close();
    $status = $row[4];
    // check status
    if ($status == "active")
    {
      // already active
    }
    else if ($status === "" || $status === NULL)
    {
      $query = "UPDATE newusers SET status='active' WHERE token='$token'";
      $connection->query($query);
      echo "Activated.";
      die("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5; url=account.php'>");
    }
  }

  echo "Why are you here?";
  die("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=index.php'>");

  $connection->close();
?>
```

Will something like this work to activate accounts? By default the status column is set to NULL... I'm just not sure if you can compare a variable to NULL even with the exact operator.

Comment: Why not try it out? https://3v4l.org/hYpSB

Comment: I'd not make a status field `NULL` by default, but `inactive`.

Comment: `if ($status = "active")` You're gonna have a problem there; using a single `=` in comparison always equates to `true`

Comment: @TimLewis worse, it assigns `"active"` to `$status` as well.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Indeed, and it would skip the second `if` check (which should maybe be an `else if`)

Comment: The exact answer for the title of your question can be found in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (the third table). `NULL` is `===` only to another `NULL` value (which is how the `===` operator works for all data types anyway). Just make sure the value in your database is a real `NULL` and not an empty string.

Comment: @TimLewis *"using a single = in comparison always equates to true"* -- this is not correct. The value of an expression that uses the [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) is the assigned value. The statement `if ($status = false) {...} else {...}` always takes the `else` branch.

Comment: As an aside: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL like this.

Comment: @axiac Ah yes, good catch. Suppose I should have adjusted to *"will equate to `true` when used like this"* (or something). My bad.

Comment: @ADyson - I thought you only had to sanitize user input. Nevermind, the $token can be easily changed. Thank you!

Comment: In all seriousness, why double check for null or empty? Just doing `if ($status == "active") { ... is active ... } else { ... not active ... }` is what you are going for.

Comment: @user10032371 `$_REQUEST[token]` (I guess you actually meant `$_REQUEST['token']`?)  _is_ user input. It comes from the client. A malicious user could visit your URL and present any value they like in this field. You may be intending to provide a pre-populated value (via some kind of activation email or something, I guess), but that doesn't stop anyone from changing it to something else.

Comment: Speaking of which ... change that to `$_REQUEST['token'];` (note quotes).

Comment: I didn't think about people modifying the URL... still new to this :)

Comment: @user10032371 now's a good time to learn! Bottom line...don't trust _anything_ which you receive via the GET, POST or REQUEST parameters. And with SQL, always use parameterised queries as a matter of course, even if you think you trust the input. Firstly it just removes any element of doubt about possible injection attacks, and secondly you save yourself a potential load of syntax pain resulting from trying to concatenate strings together in order to form a different (valid SQL) string - I'm thinking particularly of dealing with text with quote marks in it, etc.

Comment: You should also avoid doing the lazy `SELECT * FROM...` grabs. I know you are pulling `row[4]` ... but how do you actually know the right field is #4 from a wildcard grab? Its easier to read if you did like `SELECT status FROM...` and use `fetch_assoc` to get `$row['status']` to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your question:**

If the mysql has a true `NULL` for that field, doing `$status = $row[4];` will actually be assigned true `NULL` for php to compare explicitly on. So `$status === NULL` will actually work (but only if the mysql field is a true null value).

**However based on your code, all you need is:**

```
if ($row[4] == "active") {
    // its active
} else {
    // its not, so activate/do more
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for this type of thing. It checks for `null`, `false`, `0`, `''` and even empty arrays.

```
// change 
else if ($status === "" || $status === NULL)

// to
else if (empty($status))
```